# Python script not putting entire line in excel spreadsheet

Tags: python, excel

I have a Python script that pulls down HTML, strips parts that I want out of it and gives me a list that looks in part like this:

```
...
San Onofre SB
Otay Mesa
Platteville NB
Platteville SB
...
```

The last part of the script puts all of these lines into their own row in an Excel spreadsheet.  That piece of code looks like this:

```
print "Now let's put it in a spreadsheet..."
time.sleep(1)
f = open('Out.txt', 'r+') #The file that's created earlier in the script with the list
row_list = []
for row in f:
    row_list.append(row.split())
column_list = zip(*row_list)

rb = open_workbook("CVO.xls",formatting_info=True)
r_sheet = rb.sheet_by_index(0) 
wb = copy(rb) 
w_sheet = wb.get_sheet(0) 
i = 2 
for column in column_list:
    for item in range(len(column)):
        w_sheet.write(item, i, column[item])
    wb.save('CVO.xls')
    i+=1

f.close()
os.remove("Out.txt")
print "Success!"
time.sleep(2)
```

The results look in part like this:

```
...
San
Otay
Platteville
Platteville
...
```

I think the parts are being left out due to the way the rows are being split but I'm not sure how to make it include the whole line.

Any ideas?

Thank you!!

**EDIT**

The goal is to have the entire line (San Onofre SB, Otay Mesa, etc) in its own row.  It does that now, it just lops off all but the first word (turning San Onofre SB into just San).

Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: What exactly do you want your spreadsheet to contain? One row containing all the split strings? One string per row? What should be in a single cell?

Comment: Edited.  One string per row is the goal.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is with your `zip`. `zip` truncates to the shortest of its iterables, eg:

```
>>> zip(*[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5], [6, 7, 8]])
[(1, 4, 6), (2, 5, 7)]
```

Fortunately, you don't need to `zip`, and I can't tell why you're trying to do so. To write each word in separate column, just iterate through the `row_list` structure:

```
col_offset = 2
for (rownum, words) in enumerate(row_list):
    for (colnum, word) in enumerate(words):
        w_sheet.write(rownum, colnum + col_offset, word)
```

`enumerate` yields `(index, pair)` values for each element in the input iterable, so that automatically moves through the sequences. `col_offset` is because `enumerate` is 0-indexed and your example code shows `i=2` setting the starting column.

If you don't want the words in separate columns, don't split the lines - just `strip()` them to get rid of the newline. If you have to split them for previous processing, use `join()` to recombine them:

```
colnum = 2
for (rownum, words) in enumerate(row_list):
    w_sheet.write(rownum, colnum, ' '.join(words))
```

Comment: I gave this the check as it's REALLY close but not quite right.  This yielded quite an amusing result, too.  All the data it put in are slanted in the spreadsheet.  Looks pretty funny.

Anyway, it puts, for instance "Santa Nella SB" in 3 cells instead of just one...cells C1, D1 and E1.  Then, below that, "San Onofre SB" is the same way but to the right one...in D1, E1 and F1.  And so on.

Close but not quite right.  I'll have to see if I can fix it.  Thanks for the input.

Comment: I had a stray "col_offset+=1" at the bottom.  Ditched that and now it's not sprawling my data out all over the place.  However, it is still splitting every word into its own cell.

Comment: Right, that's what I was referring to with the part about not splitting the lines. I'll add code showing how you can rejoin them if you had to split them to do your earlier processing.

Comment: Oh oh.  Didn't see that.  You rock man.  100% working.  Thank you!!